# How to insert into database from List of records?

Tags: java

Please see the below code.

```
private void printToConsole(List cellDataList) {
    for (int i = 1; i < cellDataList.size(); i++) {
        List cellTempList = (List) cellDataList.get(i);
        System.out.println(cellTempList);
    }
}
```

How to get below the data to insert into database from above code.

```
String sql2 = "INSERT INTO Daily_Report (field1,field2,field3,field4,field5,field6,field7,field8,field9,field10,field11,field12,field13,field14) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
                        preparedstatement = con3.prepareStatement(sql2);
                        //Statement stmt = con3.createStatement();
                        System.out.println("1");
                        preparedstatement.setString(1, field1);
                        preparedstatement.setString(2, field2);
                        preparedstatement.setString(3, field3);
                        preparedstatement.setString(4, field4);
                        preparedstatement.setString(5, field5);
                        preparedstatement.setString(6, field6);
                        preparedstatement.setString(7, field7);
                        preparedstatement.setString(8, field8);
                        preparedstatement.setString(9, field9);
                        preparedstatement.setString(10, field10);
                        preparedstatement.setString(11, field11);
                        preparedstatement.setString(12, field12);
                        preparedstatement.setString(13, field13);
                        preparedstatement.setString(14, field14);
                        preparedstatement.executeUpdate();
```

Could you please advise...

Comment: Do you want to know what to put in place of field1 etc? What is your List<generic> type?

Comment: You want to execute the insert query for each cellTempList ?

Comment: Its array list.I have table with 14 columns as like whatever in the excel sheet.Doesn't matter need to insert each cell value or bulk update.whatever its fine for me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write this;

```
   for (int i = 0; i < cellDataList.size(); i++){
          stmt.executeUpdate ((String) cellDataList.get (i));
    }
```

Comment: How to pass the values to insert query ?

Comment: @user441978 First you need to create wrapper class, For example CellData class with 14 fields(field1, field2,...,field14) and loop this.

Answer (score 0):

something like?

```
for (int i = 0; i < rowDataList.size() && i <14; i++) {
    preparedstatement.setString(i+1, rowDataList.get(i));        
}
for (int i = rowDataList.size()+1; i <=14; i++) {
    preparedstatement.setString(i+1, "");        
}
preparedstatement.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: How to pass the values to insert query ?

Comment: rowDataList is a list of values for a particular row. the code snippet will insert the values into the db insert statement. Best way to proceed is to try it out and try to fix any errors.

Answer (score 0):

```
String sql2 = "INSERT INTO Daily_Report (field1,field2,field3,field4,field5,field6,field7,field8,field9,field10,field11,field12,field13,field14) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
preparedstatement = con3.prepareStatement(sql2);

for (int i = 1; i < cellDataList.size(); i++) {
        List cellTempList = (List) cellDataList.get(i);
        for (int i = 0; i <14; i++) {
            preparedstatement.setString(i+1, cellTempList.size() > i ? cellTempList.get(i) : "");        
        }
}
```

Assuming :

1. `cellDataList` is a list of all the rows in the excel that you are reading.
2. `cellTempList` is a list which represents a row content